# filter array of objects - remove objects when negative and positive values are matching

Tags: javascript

Array of dates -

```
const WEXDateArray = WEXFile.map((r) => r.Date);

const uniqueDateArray = WEXDateArray.filter((item, pos) => {
        return WEXDateArray.indexOf(item) == pos;
      });
```

Date sample -

```
[
  '8/2/2021',  '8/3/2021',
  '8/4/2021',  '8/5/2021',
  '8/6/2021',  '8/9/2021',
  '8/10/2021', '8/11/2021',
  '8/12/2021', '8/13/2021',
  '8/16/2021', '8/17/2021',
  '8/18/2021', '8/19/2021',
  '8/20/2021', '8/25/2021',
  '8/26/2021', '8/30/2021',
  '8/31/2021'
]
```

arrays of objects -

```
const WEXFileArraySeparatedByDates: IWEXInterfaceArrayOfArrays =
        WEXFile.reduce((r, WEX) => {
          r[WEX.Date!] = r[WEX.Date!] || [];
          r[WEX.Date!].push(WEX);
          return r;
        }, Object.create(null));


[
  {
    Date: '8/30/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '15',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  },
  {
    Date: '8/30/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '13',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  },
  {
    Date: '8/30/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '8',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  },
  {
    Date: '8/30/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '14',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  },
  {
    Date: '8/30/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '12',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  },
  {
    Date: '8/30/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '-75',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  {
    Date: '8/30/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '75',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  }
]
[
  {
    Date: '8/31/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '4000',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  },
  {
    Date: '8/31/2021',
    'Exec Qty': '2000',
    'Call/Put': 'P'
  }
]
```

Explanation - I get CSV file from client and I need to delete objects form the array of objects when 2 rows from the same exec qty return 0 when you sum them up. What I did do is to get a array with the dates only. And created a new object with arrays by the dates. What I could not do is the delete objects by this condition -

if there is on Exec Qty `[1, -2, 2, 4, 5, 6, -6]`
return `[1, 4, 5]`

And after that I'll be able to concat the arrays to new array and return the array without the `[-2, 2]`.

So here is where I'm standing right now -

```
let finalWEXArray: IWEXInterface[] = [];
      for (const date of uniqueDateArray) {
    finalWEXArray = WEXFileArraySeparatedByDates[date!];
  }
```

How can I filter the arrays by the conditions I mentioned above and store them in the `finalWEXArray`

Comment: How do you intend to convert dates into +/- numbers? Is there a specific date you are comparing them to to get an offset in days?

Comment: What if you have [1,2,-3]? Or do you only consider pairs?